# Blade templating engine - custom tags

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I've seen some mentions of custom tags for the blade templating engine, but can't find an extensive documentation for blade.

Is there anything similar to `{{ book.name|capfirst }}` from the django templating engine in blade?

Is twig a nice alternative that could suit my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make first character uppercase, use

```
{{ ucfirst($variable) }}
```

Comment: oh I can just use normal php inside the tags?

Comment: you can certainly call the functions and I guess you can do a few more things(minor operations)

Comment: sigh... it says that blade does not restrict the use of php right there in the introduction to the documentation.. blade seems to be compiled into pure php, so I doubt there are many restrictions.

Comment: yeah, it's like `{{$variable}}` gets translated into `<?php echo e($variable); ?>` , I think. Double check just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom blade directive.  Register it in the `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`'s boot method:

```
public function boot()
{
    Blade::directive('ucfirst', function($string) {
        return "<?php echo ucfirst($string); ?>";
    });
}
```

Then in your blade views you can do:

```
<h1> @ucfirst($myString) </h1>
```